# Структурированные данные. Как отобразить логотип в мессенджерах?

Tags: seo

Я не могу понять, почему не отображается логотип в мессенджерах (viber, Telegram). В Skype, когда делюсь ссылкой на сайт, то лого подтягивается. Вот мой код:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json" title="schemaOrganisation">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "url": "https://www...",
    "logo": "https://www...png",
    "contactPoint": [{
      "@type": "ContactPoint",
      "telephone": "+1...",
      "contactType": "customer service",
      "availableLanguage": "English"
    }],
    "sameAs": ["https://pinterest.com/...",
      "https://www.youtube.com/user/...",
      "https://www.facebook.com/...",
      "https://twitter.com/...",
      "https://www..."
    ],
    "email": "info@...",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "",
      "addressLocality": "",
      "addressRegion": "",
      "postalCode": "",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="application/ld+json" title="schemaBreadcrumb">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement": [{
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@id": "https://www....",
        "name": "Home"
      }
    }]
  }
</script>
<!-- Facebook structured data general-->
<meta property="og:title" content="Title..." />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www...." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_EN" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www....png" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="https://www.....png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="business:contact_data:country_name" content="US" />
<meta property="business:contact_data:email" content="info@..." />
<meta property="business:contact_data:phone_number" content="+1..." />
<meta property="business:contact_data:website" content="https://www...." />
<!-- eof Facebook structured data general-->
<!-- Twitter Card markup -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@..." />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.....png" />
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Home" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://www...." />
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="https://www...." />
<!-- eof Twitter Card markup -->
```